# Get all the facebook Application user details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Am a facebook game developer. i have developed a game and am using facebook log in facility.but still now i want store the my app user id in my database.
but am interested do Rank the user  based on their score. hence i need there all the user of my game.

so it any possibility to get the all registered user ID from Graph API/ or in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

when the user is registering your app or authorizing it, store the user details in your own table. That would be a better option. Or you have to use FQL on insights object to get the application installed users.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights

There you have a property called "application_installed_users"